# Is the field $L = \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}})$ normal over $K=\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Hey I have this exercise where I have problems understanding the solutions.

Is the field $L = \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}})$ normal over $K=\mathbb{Q}$?

What we have done is:
$a=\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}$ is a root of the polynomial $f(x)=(x^2-2)^2-2=x^4-4x^2+2 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$
With Eisenstein we see that is irreducible and therefore $[\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}]=4$

The polynomial $f(x)$ has following roots: $a,-a,\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}},-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$ so we can write $f(x)$ as linear factors: $f(x)=(x-a)(x+a)(x-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}})(x+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}})$.

Each of this roots are in $L$ and therefore is the field normal over $\mathbb{Q}$

Now, what I am not nunderstanding is how we can say that $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$ is in $L$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the product
$$
\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt2} = \sqrt{2^2-\sqrt2^2} = \sqrt2
$$
Clearly this is an element of $L$ (it's equal to $a^2 - 2$). And since $\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}\in L$ as well, then
$$
\sqrt{2-\sqrt2} = \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}
$$
must also be in $L$

Comment: It is not difficult to find duplicates with help form [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cmathbb%7BQ%7D(%20%5Csqrt%7B2%20%2B%20%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%7D)%24&p=1).